# How to change blue stacks 2 resolution by regedit

Tags: regedit, bluestacks

In original blue stacks, users can change the resolution by reg file.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0]
> "WindowWidth"=dword:00000500
>  "WindowHeight"=dword:00000320
> "GuestWidth"=dword:00000500
>  "GuestHeight"=dword:00000320

Is there similar way for BlueStacks 2?

Comment: The latest version already support it.

Comment: Not really, you can only scale Width down to about 600 pixels

Comment: What about MacOSX?

Comment: No idea about Mac OSX